# Google Spreadsheet -> Google Calendar [errors, & code help]

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I've been using a script to pull data from a Google Spreadsheet and use that info to populate a Google Calendar. It works for the most part, but is very unstable: sometimes it does not work, and most times it generates an error, even if it does work.

One error I get a lot is "Cannot find method createAllDayEvent(string,number,object). (line 39, file "")", which, of course, does not make much sense, as that is a known valid method.

Below is my code: I would be super grateful to anyone who can help me tweak it to be a bit more reliable:

Thanks,
Sterling

```
function SpreadsheetToCalendar() 
{
 // This function should be executed from the spreadsheet you want to export to the calendar
 var mySpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

 // These 2 methods do the same thing. Using the 2nd one, as 1st is deprecated
 // var myCalendar = CalendarApp.openByName("Autodesk Renewals");
 var myCalendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("rfx.com_bp79fdqvbortgmv21bj8am4hjc@group.calendar.google.com");

  // optional - delete existing events
  var events = myCalendar.getEvents(new Date("January 1, 2013 PST"), 
      new Date("December 31, 2016 PST"));
  for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) 
  {
     events[i].deleteEvent();
     Utilities.sleep(300); // pause in the loop for 300 milliseconds
  }

  var dataRange = mySpreadsheet.getRange("A2:H300");
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  // process the data
  for (i in data) 
  {
      var row = data[i];
      // assume that each row contains a date entry and a text entry
    var theContract = row[0] ;
    var theDate  = row[2] ;
    var theCustomer = row[3] ;
    var theAssign = row[5] ;
    var theStatus = row[6] ; 
    var theNotes = row[7] ;

    //var theTitle = (theCustomer + " | " + theContract + " | " + theAssign + " | " + theStatus);
    var theTitle = ("| " + theCustomer + " | " + theContract + " | " + theAssign + " | " + theStatus + " |");

    //myCalendar.createAllDayEvent(theTitle, theDate);
    // myCalendar.createAllDayEvent(theTitle, new Date(date));
    myCalendar.createAllDayEvent(theTitle, theDate, {description:theNotes});
    Utilities.sleep(300); // pause in the loop for 300 milliseconds
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

as for the specific error regarding createAllDayEvent, note that each parameter has a type. your code is not validating that the cell from row[2] has a valid date and instead its passing a number, which is not expected.

you are also doing a for..in.. on an array which is bad (google it. tldr you will loop on the "count" property too.)

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I realized that some of my dates weren't formatted correctly, which fixed that error. Explains why it was intermittent too. I'll look into it more, but is there another method you'd suggest for the for/in on the array portion?

Comment: google that last question. its a super common mistake to use for...in for arrays. use for (i=0...)

Comment: I think I managed to add the date validation for row[2], but I'm still not sure what to do to fix the for/in array issue. (I'm a pretty novice coder plugging through this)

Also, is there a way to clear all items in a given calendar instead of deleting them by going through the array? The current method I'm using often creates the following error: "You have been creating or deleting too many calendars or calendar events in a short time. Please try again later."

Comment: do google the for..in issue. if you want to learn coding you must investigate. a trivial google search for "javascript array for in" has the first result as the explanation you are asking here. Also, you cant delete many events at once. To handle those type of "rate" issues see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/best_practices

Comment: So @ZigMandel, I found some info at http://www.sebarmeli.com/blog/2010/12/06/best-way-to-loop-through-an-array-in-javascript/

Looks like I should be replacing "for (i in data)" with "for (i=0; i < data.length; i++)"

Seem legit?